# replace button text with .replaceWith()

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is not seeming to work for me [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jo99ksk9/1/)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.dropdown-menu>li>a').on("click", function() {
        var buttonText = $(this).text();
        $('.dropdown-toggle').replaceWith(buttonText);
    });
});
```

Comment: Remove the variable and just use `$('.dropdown-toggle').text($(this).text());`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.dropdown-menu > li > a').on("click", function() {
    var buttonText = $(this).text();
    $('.dropdown-toggle').text(buttonText);
  });
});
```

Your query selector was incorrectly using `dropdown` instead of `dropdown-menu`. Also, `replaceWith()` will replace the entire element, so it's best to use `.text()` to just change the inner text of the button.

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.dropdown-menu>li>a').on("click", function() {
        var buttonText = $(this).text();
        $('.dropdown-toggle').text(buttonText);
    });
});
```

Face Palm!